# php alerts and google captcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a password request page, I am using the google captcha, my question is how to have them fire both same time.

http://www.camteach.com/user-password-request.php

If i click submit without completeing anything i have both the warning of "Please check the anti-spam 'I am not a robot' checkbox!" AND "No email specified!"

```
<?php function validateGoogleCaptcha(){
$errorsAndAlerts = "";

if (!@$_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'])     { $errorsAndAlerts .= "Please check the anti-spam 'I am not a robot' checkbox!<br/>\n"; }
else { 
  // check recaptcha
  $postdata = array();
  $postdata['secret']   = '6LcwKCwUAAAAAK5CXed1YJGfMk7iVBL5NgN2vPVd';
  $postdata['response'] = @$_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'];
  $postdata['remoteip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?". http_build_query($postdata, '', '&');
  list($json, $httpStatusCode, $headers, $request) = getPage($url, 5, '', true);
  $recaptchaResponse = json_decode($json, true);

  if (!$recaptchaResponse['success']) {
    if (is_array($recaptchaResponse['error-codes'])) { 
      if (in_array('missing-input-secret', $recaptchaResponse['error-codes']))     { $errorsAndAlerts .= "There's a problem with recaptcha, please let us know! (no secret)<br/>\n"; }
      if (in_array('invalid-input-secret', $recaptchaResponse['error-codes']))     { $errorsAndAlerts .= "There's a problem with recaptcha, please let us know! (invald secret)<br/>\n"; }
      if (in_array('missing-input-response', $recaptchaResponse['error-codes']))   { $errorsAndAlerts .= "Please fill out the recaptcha box!<br/>\n"; }
      if (in_array('invalid-input-response', $recaptchaResponse['error-codes']))   { $errorsAndAlerts .= "Please fill out the recaptcha box again, your answer was incorrect!<br/>\n"; }
    }
    if (!$errorsAndAlerts) { $errorsAndAlerts .= "Invalid captcha response, please try again or contact us directly and let us know."; }
    @trigger_error("Failed recaptcha on signup form", E_USER_NOTICE);
  }
 }

 return $errorsAndAlerts;
 }
// error checking
 $errorsAndAlerts = alert();
if (@$CURRENT_USER) {
$errorsAndAlerts = "You are already logged in! <a href='/'>Click here to continue</a> or <a href='?action=logoff'>Logoff</a>.";
}
?>
<?php // process form
if (@$_POST['action']):?>
<?php  $errorsAndAlerts = "";
$errorsAndAlerts .= validateGoogleCaptcha(); 
?>
<?php endif ?>
<?php 
### send reset email
if (@$_POST['action'] == 'sendPasswordReminder') {
global $SETTINGS, $TABLE_PREFIX;

// display errors
if (!@$_REQUEST['usernameOrEmail']) { $errorsAndAlerts .= "No email specified!<br/>\n"; }

// send emails
if (@$_REQUEST['usernameOrEmail']) {
  $where = mysql_escapef("? IN (`username`,`email`)", $_REQUEST['usernameOrEmail']);
  $user  = mysql_get(accountsTable(), null, $where);

  // send message
  if ($user) {

    $emailHeaders = emailTemplate_loadFromDB(array(
      'template_id'  => 'USER-PASSWORD-RESET',
      'placeholders' => array(
        'user.username' => $user['username'],
        'user.email'    => $user['email'],
        'loginUrl'      => realUrl($GLOBALS['WEBSITE_LOGIN_LOGIN_FORM_URL']),
        'resetUrl'      => realUrl($GLOBALS['WEBSITE_LOGIN_RESET_URL'] . "?userNum={$user['num']}&resetCode=" . _generatePasswordResetCode( $user['num'] )),
    )));
    $mailErrors = sendMessage($emailHeaders);
    if ($mailErrors) { alert("Mail Error: $mailErrors"); }

    //
    $errorsAndAlerts .= "Thanks, we've emailed you instructions on resetting your password.<br/><br/>
    If you don't receive an email within a few minutes check your spam filter for messages from elvis himself<br/>\n";

    // clear form
    $_REQUEST['usernameOrEmail'] = '';
  }

  //
  if (!$user) { $errorsAndAlerts .= "No matching username or email was found!<br/>\n"; }
}
```

}
?>

Were I to just click the Googles "I am not a robot" captcha,,,, I get the "No email specified!" alert

but were I to not check the captcha, and just enter an email address, on this occasion enter emmalinnery@gmail.com, and it goes through. I want it so when the correct email is entered and captcha is not checked to have the alert show "Please check the anti-spam 'I am not a robot' checkbox!"

I would be grateful for any input. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution, add a $captcha variable at the top and add this code

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo "<script> alert('Please check the the captcha form.'); </script>";
    }
```

I recommend using this tutorial, it helped me a lot

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/google-recaptcha-tutorial/

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my captcha has more than one error message/alert.